# C++ Linux Async HTTP POST (Boost::asio)

Tags: c++, linux, http, boost-asio

I have spent the last two days trying to make an async http POST with libcurl and I think I'm giving up on it. `curl_multi_fdset` is giving me -1 for the number of file descriptors arg and the documentation simply states "it means there's an error with your application". Making a synchronous call was very simply, but that is of course worthless.

Boost::asio seems promising but I can't find any examples of how to do an http POST.

If someone would be kind enough to show me an example of that I could stop pulling my hair out.

Comment: You're going to need to post some kind of sample code if you want help with libcurl -- that function is one API in a big framework.  And what's wrong with synchronous I/O in your application?  It's certainly not "worthless".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html) is something I think you may find useful. It is a C++ simple to use HTTP library based on boost.